# Converting docx into pdf in java

Tags: java, pdf, ms-word, apache-poi

I am trying to convert a `docx` file which contains table and images into a `pdf` format file.

I have been searching everywhere but did not get proper solution, request to give proper and correct solution:

*here what i have tried :*

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

public class TestCon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestCon cwoWord = new TestCon();
        System.out.println("Start");
        cwoWord.ConvertToPDF("D:\\Test.docx", "D:\\Test1.pdf");
    }

    public void ConvertToPDF(String docPath, String pdfPath) {
        try {
            InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(new File(docPath));
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(doc);
            PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(pdfPath));
            PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log(ILjava/lang/Object;)V from class org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.parseRelationshipsPart(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:313)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:162)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:130)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.loadRelationships(PackagePart.java:559)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:112)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:83)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:128)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart.<init>(ZipPackagePart.java:78)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:239)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:665)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:274)
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:121)
at test.TestCon.ConvertToPDF(TestCon.java:31)
at test.TestCon.main(TestCon.java:25)
```

My requirement is to create a java code to convert existing docx into pdf with proper format and alignment.

Please suggest.

Jars Used:

[image: Updated jars]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert MS doc to pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022376/how-to-convert-ms-doc-to-pdf)

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki may be , but i did not get help from that question though.

Comment: here is also another answer if you insist on ApachePOI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201736/javausing-apache-poi-how-to-convert-ms-word-file-to-pdf

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki i am getting The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)

Comment: Your question is not about Apache (the webserver) or about iText, so I removed those tags. I added the more specific tag `apache-poi` instead. It's also frowned upon to tag someone who is not contributing to a question.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse yeah , but BrunoLowagie is the creator of iText i thought he will help

Comment: Bruno would only be able to help if your question is about iText. But your question is not about iText, it is about Apache POI. Anyway, if you tag someone who has not commented, then they will NOT get notified when you tag them. Stack Overflow does this to prevent tag spamming, which is the description of what you did.

Comment: No one will be able to help you if you keep changing the goal post. In the last 15 minutes, you have edited the post many times and changed the libraries as many times.

Comment: @VivekRatanSinha I am trying different possibilities , Can you help in code which will convert docx into pdf with tables.

Comment: In one of your many, many edits, you have `com.lowagie` in your exception. (I can see the edit history)
This means that you are using an *ancient* version of iText, 2.1.7 or older, that's at least 8 years old. Since you seem to trust on the expertise of Bruno Lowagie, you should be familiar with his opinion about people who still use such an old iText version.

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` - if you get such errors, you most likely use a combination of library versions which are not compatible. Look into the respective documentations to discover required dependency versions.

Comment: @Sam I would appreciate if you mark my answer as Accepted :)

Comment: @VivekRatanSinha Can you share the code with all libraries used, becuase i am getting java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log Error

Comment: @VivekRatanSinha Thank you sir

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are missing some libraries.

I am able to run your code by adding the following libraries:

```
    Apache POI 3.15
    org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-1.0.6.jar
    org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.6.jar
    fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension-2.0.0.jar
    itext-2.1.7.jar
    ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar
```

I have successfully converted a 6 pages long Word document (.docx) with tables, images and various formatting.

Comment: Just a note, this is not using POI to do the conversion despite the package names. Only the `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar` is from Apache POI. The rest are from the `opensagres` and `itext` projects.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy My approach was not to reinvent the wheel, just to get the code in question to work.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your answer, just didn't want anyone to get the wrong idea that the `org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.*` packages were a part of Apache POI.

Comment: Thank you Sir , It helped me

Comment: Where did you find the ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar file? I see only newer versions: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml

Comment: @BakedInhalf The location is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.3

Comment: @VivekRatanSinha I also tried with POI 3.17 and 3.16. None of them worked, so it seems they changed something after version 3.15

Comment: For anyone still trying to convert with XDocReport and POI 4.0.x (w/o itext), new version of XDocReport has a differrent artifact id (`fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf` instead of `org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf`) and package structure than the older ones. e.g. 

`<dependency>
  <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
  <artifactId>fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
`

Comment: I tried follow this get error : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException

Comment: @superup your classpath does have xmlbeans.jar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022376/how-can-i-convert-a-word-document-to-pdf/65403145#65403145 - I hope this is best method convert docx to pdf.

Answer (score 31):

In addition to the VivekRatanSinha [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43363624/converting-docx-into-pdf-in-java/43367266#43367266), i would i like to post full code and required jars for the people who need it in future.

**Code:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

public class WordConvertPDF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordConvertPDF cwoWord = new WordConvertPDF();
        cwoWord.ConvertToPDF("D:/Test.docx", "D:/Test.pdf");
    }

    public void ConvertToPDF(String docPath, String pdfPath) {
        try {
            InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(new File(docPath));
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(doc);
            PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(pdfPath));
            PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**and JARS:**

[image: required jars]

Enjoy :)

Comment: @user1999397 can you provide complete sample because the libs having dependencies on each other

Comment: please add pom instead of jars image.

Comment: I follow your code and lib get error : No valid entries or contents found, this is not a valid OOXML (Office Open XML) file.

Answer (score 17):

I will provide 3 methods to convert docx to pdf :

1. **Using itext and opensagres and apache poi**

*Code :*

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions;
import fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

public class ConvertDocToPdfitext {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println( "Starting conversion!!!" );
    ConvertDocToPdfitext cwoWord = new ConvertDocToPdfitext();
    cwoWord.ConvertToPDF("C:/Users/avijit.shaw/Desktop/testing/docx/Account Opening Prototype Details.docx", "C:/Users/avijit.shaw/Desktop/testing/docx/Test-1.pdf");
    System.out.println( "Ending conversion!!!" );
  }

  public void ConvertToPDF(String docPath, String pdfPath) {
    try {
        InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(new File(docPath));
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(doc);
        PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(pdfPath));
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

*Dependencies: Use Maven to resolve dependencies.*

New version 2.0.2 of fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core runs with apache poi 4.0.1 and itext 2.17. You just need to add below dependency in Maven and then maven will auto download all dependent dependencies. (Updated your Maven project, so it downloaded all these libraries and all of its dependencies)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
    <artifactId>fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2. **Using  Documents4j**

Note:  You need to have MS Office installed on the machine in which this code is running.

*Code :*

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.documents4j.api.DocumentType;
import com.documents4j.api.IConverter;
import com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter;

public class Document4jApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      File inputWord = new File("C:/Users/avijit.shaw/Desktop/testing/docx/Account Opening Prototype Details.docx");
      File outputFile = new File("Test_out.pdf");
      try  {
          InputStream docxInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputWord);
          OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
          IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder().build();         
          converter.convert(docxInputStream).as(DocumentType.DOCX).to(outputStream).as(DocumentType.PDF).execute();
          outputStream.close();
          System.out.println("success");
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

*Dependencies : Use Maven to resolve dependencies.*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>documents4j-local</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>documents4j-transformer-msoffice-word</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

3. **Using openoffice nuoil**

Note:  You need to have OpenOffice installed on the machine in which this code is running.
*Code :*

```
import java.io.File;
import com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue;
import com.sun.star.comp.helper.BootstrapException;
import com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader;
import com.sun.star.frame.XDesktop;
import com.sun.star.frame.XStorable;
import com.sun.star.lang.XComponent;
import com.sun.star.lang.XMultiComponentFactory;
import com.sun.star.uno.Exception;
import com.sun.star.uno.UnoRuntime;
import com.sun.star.uno.XComponentContext;

import ooo.connector.BootstrapSocketConnector;

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, BootstrapException {
      System.out.println("Stating conversion!!!");
      // Initialise
      String oooExeFolder = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenOffice 4\\program"; //Provide path on which OpenOffice is installed
      XComponentContext xContext = BootstrapSocketConnector.bootstrap(oooExeFolder);
      XMultiComponentFactory xMCF = xContext.getServiceManager();
  
      Object oDesktop = xMCF.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", xContext);
  
      XDesktop xDesktop = (XDesktop) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XDesktop.class, oDesktop);
  
      // Load the Document
      String workingDir = "C:/Users/avijit.shaw/Desktop/testing/docx/"; //Provide directory path of docx file to be converted
      String myTemplate = workingDir + "Account Opening Prototype Details.docx"; // Name of docx file to be converted
  
      if (!new File(myTemplate).canRead()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot load template:" + new File(myTemplate));
      }
  
      XComponentLoader xCompLoader = (XComponentLoader) UnoRuntime
          .queryInterface(com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader.class, xDesktop);
  
      String sUrl = "file:///" + myTemplate;
  
      PropertyValue[] propertyValues = new PropertyValue[0];
  
      propertyValues = new PropertyValue[1];
      propertyValues[0] = new PropertyValue();
      propertyValues[0].Name = "Hidden";
  

          propertyValues[0].Value = new Boolean(true);
  
      XComponent xComp = xCompLoader.loadComponentFromURL(sUrl, "_blank", 0, propertyValues);
  
      // save as a PDF
      XStorable xStorable = (XStorable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XStorable.class, xComp);
  
      propertyValues = new PropertyValue[2];
      // Setting the flag for overwriting
      propertyValues[0] = new PropertyValue();
      propertyValues[0].Name = "Overwrite";
      propertyValues[0].Value = new Boolean(true);
      // Setting the filter name
      propertyValues[1] = new PropertyValue();
      propertyValues[1].Name = "FilterName";
      propertyValues[1].Value = "writer_pdf_Export";
  
      // Appending the favoured extension to the origin document name
      String myResult = workingDir + "letterOutput.pdf"; // Name of pdf file to be output
      xStorable.storeToURL("file:///" + myResult, propertyValues);
  
      System.out.println("Saved " + myResult);
  
      // shutdown
      xDesktop.terminate();
  }
}
```

*Dependencies : Use Maven to resolve dependencies.*

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openoffice/unoil -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openoffice</groupId>
        <artifactId>unoil</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openoffice/juh -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openoffice</groupId>
        <artifactId>juh</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openoffice/bootstrap-connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openoffice</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap-connector</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Remember to call `converter.shutDown();` after `execute();` when using Documents4j.

Comment: in rtl languages opensagres have not suitable output, but Documents4j is ok.

Answer (score 8):

I have done a lot of research and found Documents4j is the best free API for converting docx to pdf. **Alignment**, **font** everything documents4j doing good job.

Maven Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>documents4j-local</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>documents4j-transformer-msoffice-word</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Use the below code for convert docx to pdf.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.documents4j.api.DocumentType;
import com.documents4j.api.IConverter;
import com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter;

public class Document4jApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File inputWord = new File("Tests.docx");
        File outputFile = new File("Test_out.pdf");
        try  {
            InputStream docxInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputWord);
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder().build();
            converter.convert(docxInputStream).as(DocumentType.DOCX).to(outputStream).as(DocumentType.PDF).execute();
            outputStream.close();
            System.out.println("success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: issue with `documents4j` that it requires MS components to be insatlled, hence it will hardly work on Linux for instance. https://github.com/documents4j/documents4j/issues/41

Comment: Remember to call `converter.shutDown();` after `execute();`

Comment: @povis, yes you are correct documents4j not working in linux environment. Use docx4j for both windows and linux enviornment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022376/how-can-i-convert-a-word-document-to-pdf/65403145#65403145

Comment: This is the only java opensource library that worked for my docx->pdf conversion. I've tried these 3 libraries:,apache POI, fr.opensagres(which use apache POI for conversion) and docx4j. Thx @Sathia . This was tested on Windows machine.

Comment: Be AWARE. this is not working in UNIX based system. Unfortunately this worked for me like a charm in Windows local machine, but in Bamboo is not..

Answer (score 8):

If your document is pretty rich and your option is to do the converting on Linux/Unix then [all three main options suggested in the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59624576/2852528) could be "a bit" painful to implement.

A solution which I might suggest is to use [Gotenberg](https://github.com/thecodingmachine/gotenberg/): *A Docker-powered stateless API for converting HTML, Markdown and Office documents to PDF.*

- launch the container `$ docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 thecodingmachine/gotenberg:7`
- make a request to the container. Here is how to use `curl`:

```bash
$ curl \
    --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/forms/libreoffice/convert' \
    --form 'files=@"/path/to/file.docx"' \
    -o result.pdf
```

Deploy it to your infrastructure (e.g. as a separate microservice) and shoot it from your Java service making that simple HTTP request. Get your PDF file in the response and do what you want with it.

Tested, and works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add these maven dependencies

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-examples</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only ONE dependency needs to manually added (the others should be pulled in automatically). As of right now, the latest version is 2.0.2.

Gradle:

```java
dependencies {
    // What you should already have
    implementation "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:latest.release"


    // ADD THE BELOW LINE TO DEPENDENCIES BLOCK IN build.gradle
    implementation 'fr.opensagres.xdocreport:fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf:2.0.2'
}
```

Maven only:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
    <artifactId>fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Docx4j is **open source** and the best API for convert Docx to pdf without any alignment or font issue.

**Maven Dependencies**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-Internal</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-MOXy</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j-export-fo</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Code**:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.docx4j.Docx4J;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart;

public class DocToPDF {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            InputStream templateInputStream = new FileInputStream("D:\\\\Workspace\\\\New\\\\Sample.docx");
            WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(templateInputStream);
            MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

            String outputfilepath = "D:\\\\Workspace\\\\New\\\\Sample.pdf";
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputfilepath);
            Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage,os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (Throwable e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very complex document and Microsoft Graph Api helped to produce the correct pdf with the exact formatting as in the input Docx

The following links help complete App Registration for setting up the API key/secrets to access the Graph Api
https://medium.com/medialesson/convert-files-to-pdf-using-microsoft-graph-azure-functions-20bc84d2adc4

https://devzigma.com/java/upload-files-to-sharepoint-using-java/

Once the docx document is uploaded, see this to be able to download the pdf version of the same docx: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content-format?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java

Answer (score 0):

I use this code.

```
private byte[] toPdf(ByteArrayOutputStream docx) {
    InputStream isFromFirstData = new ByteArrayInputStream(docx.toByteArray());

    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(isFromFirstData);
    PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();

    //make new file in c:\temp\
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\tmp\\HelloWord.pdf"));
    PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);

    //return byte array for return in http request.
    ByteArrayOutputStream pdf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, pdf, options);

    document.write(pdf);
    document.close();
    return pdf.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Let me give you an example in Kotlin
With dependencies that work for me (the method from the question did not change)

```
//gradle.kts
implementation("fr.opensagres.xdocreport:fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf:2.0.4")
implementation("org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:3.0.0")
```

kotlin

```
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument
import java.io.*
import fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter
import fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions

fun ConvertToPDF(docPath: String?, pdfPath: String?) {
    try {
        val doc: InputStream = FileInputStream(File(docPath))
        val document = XWPFDocument(doc)
        val options = PdfOptions.create()
        val out: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(File(pdfPath))
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options)
        println("Done")
    } catch (ex: FileNotFoundException) {
        println(ex.message)
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        println(ex.message)
    }
}
```

Comment: OP is looking for Java