# Shapes/text box gets removed after converting docx to pdf in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx-to-pdf-conversion

I tried with  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59624576) (with apache poi) to convert docx to pdf and it converts it but my docx file contains some shapes/text boxes and after conversion it removes them.
I cant use MS Office as my code is hosted on cloud.

Also, tried other solutions from above link but they are not working as expected.

This is the result I get after running the code. The content in the text-box(2nd image) is removed.
Contents in docx:
[docx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tL74.png)

Contents in pdf after conversion:
[pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qusw.png)